# Give a non-constant value to interval expression

Tags: sql, vertica

For the following sql expression:

```
some_timstamp_field RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '5' second PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
```

I want to change the constant value `'5'` to a value of some field in my table (and thus this value won't be a constant).

is it possible to do it?

Comment: I don't think that is possible in window frame specifications in Vertica.  You might ask another question with sample data and desired results to see if there is another way to address what you want to do.

Comment: Try dynamic SQL, in the sense that you write SQL via a shell or Python script. You manage your interval variable from there.

Comment: As in practically all DBMSs abiding at least roughly to the ANSI standard in OLAP functions, the `RANGE BETWEEN PRECEDING ... AND FOLLOWING ...` interval expressions have to be constant literals. As @minatverma points out, SQL generating SQL can be your friend. But, also, try to put , for example, two different sets of identifiers together in a time series data sample you'd paste into your question, each identifier requireing a different interval in the `RANGE`, and what you need to achieve. Vertica has  time series functionalities that could help you solve the business problem differently

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic interval expression outside the window frame you can use CAST(*val* AS INTERVAL *interval_name*):

```
SELECT NOW(), NOW() - CAST(interval_col AS INTERVAL SECOND)
FROM
(
        SELECT 5 AS interval_col UNION ALL
        SELECT 10
)t
```

But for window frame it is not allowed, you will get the error:

```
ERROR: Window frame logical or physical offset must be a constant
```

**UPDATE:**
Assuming you want to count a number of records for a dynamic time frame against current record timestamp, the solution could be the following:

```
WITH intervals AS
(
        SELECT '1 seconds' AS interval_name, CAST(1 AS INTERVAL SECOND) AS interval_value UNION ALL
        SELECT '5 seconds', CAST(5 AS INTERVAL SECOND) UNION ALL
        SELECT '10 seconds', CAST(10 AS INTERVAL SECOND)
), tnow AS
(
        SELECT NOW() AS ts
), tsdata AS(
        SELECT 4 as id, ts FROM tnow UNION ALL
        SELECT 3, ts - INTERVAL '3 second' FROM tnow UNION ALL
        SELECT 2, ts - INTERVAL '6 second' FROM tnow UNION ALL
        SELECT 1, ts - INTERVAL '20 second' FROM tnow
)
SELECT i.interval_name, t1.Id, t1.ts, COUNT(t2.id)
FROM tsdata t1
CROSS JOIN intervals i 
LEFT JOIN tsdata t2 ON t2.ts BETWEEN t1.ts - i.interval_value AND t1.ts
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY 1,2,3
```